# Quitar ceros en medio de un número

Tags: c

Necesito quitarle los ceros a un número en C, pero los números están en medio y no sé cómo sacarlos.

Ej: Tengo el 105 y necesito convertirlo en 15.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo harías en papel?, sin una computadora. Escribe el algoritmo para lograrlo manualmente y, diría que a partir de allí, trasladarlo a un lenguaje de programación no será tan complicado.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que el número inicial es un entero, primero lo convierto a string para poder manipular los digitos con facilidad usando `sprintf`, que me permite "imprimir" en un arreglo de caracteres.

```
int numero = 1050;
char buffer[20];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", numero);
```

En `buffer` queda "1050".

Sólo hay que eliminar los ceros entremedio, no los que puedan haber al final. Para evitar eliminarlo, tengo que determinar la posición del último dígito  no-cero.

```
int i = 0;
int last = 0;
for (i = 0; buffer[i]; i++) {
    if (buffer[i] != '0') {
        last = i;
    }
}
```

Teniendo el valor expresado como caracteres en buffer, ahora lo recorre trayendo hacia adelante sólo los digitos distintos de cero:

```
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= last; i++) {
    if (buffer[i] != '0') {
        buffer[j++] = buffer[i];
    }
}
```

Y finalmente copiamos cualquier cero a la cola:

```
while (buffer[i]) {
    buffer[j++] = buffer[i++];
}
buffer[j] = 0;
```

Finalmente, en buffer tengo el valor limpio de ceros.

```
int valor = atoi(buffer);
printf("%d", valor);
```

produce

```
150
```

Comment: Por favor, no respondas a preguntas que no tengan un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).